# Trying to convert UIImage to PFFileObject in Swift 5.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, uiimage

I'm using Parse (hosted by back4app) as backend for an iOS project. My problem is that I can't figure out how to convert an UIImage to PFFileObject.

I've tried

```
let image: UIImage = getSelectedUIImage()
let parseUser.profileImage = image
```

and

```
let image: UIImage = getSelectedUIImage()
let parseUser.profileImage = image.pngData()
```

The error shown by Xcode is "Cannot assign value of type 'UIImage?' to type 'PFFileObject?'" or "Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'PFFileObject?'".
I think that it's necessary to convert that UIImage to Binary, but I don't know how and google isn't a big help at that point...

Any hint or advice is appreciated!

Stay healthy!

Comment: Hi! Have you already checked the opensource documentation? It might help you with that, here's the link: http://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#files

Comment: Hi Charles, thanks for that hint. I've read the documentation, but overlooked the specific point you shared here. Was probably to late last night :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Charles hint to "RTFM" I could solve this "problem" with following Code:

```
let image: UIImage = getSelectedUIImage()
let imageData = image.pngData()
let pfFile = PFFileObject(name:"avatar.png", data: imageData)
parseUser.avatar = pfFile
do {
    // Better use saveInBackground() here
    try parseUser.avatar.save()
}
catch {}
parseUser.save()
```

Comment: Good to hear that you were able to solve that! Thanks for sharing your solution too :)